# Typo3 Formhandler : How to validate at least one of two fields in typoscript

Tags: typo3, typoscript

I'm using formhandler extension v1.6.2 and Typo3 v6.1.5.

User must upload a CV or fill in LinkedIn ID. If none of the fields are filled, an error should appear and the form should not be submitted.
So, I would like to add typoscript conditions but it doesn't work :

HTML

```
<input type="file" id="file" name="cv[file]">
<input type="text" size="20" id="linkedin" name="cv[linkedin]">
```

Typoscript

```
plugin.Tx_Formhandler.settings {
   if {
       1 {
           conditions {
               OR1 {
                   AND1 = file=
                   AND2 = linkedin=
               }
               isTrue {
                   validators.1.config.fieldConf.linkedin.errorCheck.1 = required
               }
          }
       }
   }
}
```

Thanks for any help !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I understand, it should be enough to make the file required if the text field is empty, right? Then try this:

```
plugin.Tx_Formhandler.settings {
    if {
        1 {
            conditions.OR1.AND1 = linkedin=
            isTrue {
                validators.1.config.fieldConf.file.errorCheck.1 = fileRequired
            }
        }
    }
}
```

BTW: using the `predef` stuff is much cleaner and safer if you have multiple forms on your site.